# python multiprocess queue always empty

Tags: python, threadpool

For no reason, even after I put some items in the queue, it still shows me

`Queue.empty() == True`

The workers are running using a separate process from the Flask one. If I'm trying to add item to the queue using some Flask sub and then checking if the queue is not empty (using another Flask sub), I can see the queue is full. But I'm still getting "queue is empty" from the `workerJob` sub.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Pool


imgQueue = Queue()

@app.route("/send", methods=["POST"])
def sendToQueue():
    # global imgQueue

    imgLocation = request.headers.get('fileLocation')
    nImage = request.data

    imgQueue.put({"location": imgLocation,
                  "image": nImage})


    return "ok"

def workerJob(q):


    while True:
        print(q.empty())
        if (not q.empty()):

            itemFromQueue = q.get()
            print(str(type(itemFromQueue)))
            print(itemFromQueue["location"])
            print(itemFromQueue["image"])


        else:
            print("Queue empty")


        time.sleep(3)

def startWorkers():
    global imgQueue

    while True:
        procs = [Process(target=workerJob, args=(imgQueue,)) for i in range(1)]
        for p in procs:
            p.start()

def flaskThread():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
  flaskProcess = Process(target=flaskThread, args=())
  flaskProcess.start()
  workerProcess = Process(target=startWorkers, args=())
  workerProcess.start()
```

Comment: Depending on how much effort you are willing to take, this is a _really_ broad question (multi-threading vs. multi-processing, job/task queues, process managers, inter-process/-thread communication ...).

Comment: The code you posted never actually places anything on the queue, so I'd expect an empty queue here. You should add the code that enqueues items if you'd like people to help debug that part of the program.

Comment: Also, it's a bit odd to run the `startWorkers` method in a separate process...since that just starts other processes. I'd recommend just starting the processes which run `workerJob` directly from the main process.

Comment: @bnaecker iv'e added the code that puts the data inside the queue.
i can't find the problem. i keep changing the code but the queue keep staing empty. no metter if i use global or not